# Systole of Riemann surfaces of genus $g$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

**[Already asked in mathoverflow]** In Buser and Sarnak's "*On the period matrix of a Riemann surface
of large genus*", we get
$$\frac4{3}\le\limsup_{g\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\max\{\operatorname{sys}(S)|S\in\mathcal{M}_g\}}{\log g}\le 2$$
Here $\operatorname{sys}(S)$ is the shortest length of closed noncontractible geodesics in $S$ and $\mathcal{M}_g$ is the moduli space. However, I want to ask if there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$\liminf_{g\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\max\{\operatorname{sys}(S)|S\in\mathcal{M}_g\}}{\log g}\ge C\quad ?$$
Any help will be appreciated.